# pandas.to_datetime format is not recognized

Tags: pandas

I  have the following dataseries:

```
Weather['date'].head()
Out[2]:
0    2019-08-31 23:00:00
1    2019-09-01 00:00:00
2    2019-09-01 01:00:00
3    2019-09-01 02:00:00
```

I use the following code

```
Weather['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Weather['date'],format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\segor\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 1858, in objects_to_datetime64ns
    values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 200, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

.
.
.
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 481, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 620, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
ValueError: time data 0 doesn't match format specified
```

Is it possible to help?

Comment: Specifyparameter (errors='coerce' ) in to_datetime method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error means there is some value `0` in datetime column, you can convert column to datetimes with missing values for this problematic data with parameter `errors='coerce'`:

```
Weather['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Weather['date'],
                                      format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', 
                                      errors='coerce')
```

Or:

```
Weather['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Weather['date'], errors='coerce')
```

Then if need remove rows with missing values for `timestamp` column use:

```
Weather = Weather.dropna(subset=['timestamp'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is the clue here:

```
time data 0 doesn't match format specified
```

Check that all the rows is your dataframe have a valid entry in the `timestamp` column.